# Структура автоматического удаления элементов

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Хелло. Я только учусь, так что не судите строго) У меня стоит задача спроектировать такую структуру, в которую можно добавлять какие-то элементы, и при этом они автоматически удаляются через 30 сек. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать. Использовать Observer, Observerable? Или можно в тупую написать метод проверки времени существования всех элементов и запускать его каждую секунду, но это будет как-то уж совсем не эффективно. Подскажите с какой стороны подойти. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Наследуешь любой контейнер элементов из стандартных, метод добавления перекрываешь добавляя получение текущего времени.
2. Если контейнер не является очередью, добавляешь в него дополнительную очередь FIFO в которую скидываешь ссылку (индекс в массиве или ключ, или что нибудь ещё) на объект + время, т.е.
3. При добавлении стартуешь отдельный поток, который проверяет очередь и в случае пустоты уходит в wait
4. При добавлении элемента будишь поток notify
5. При наличии элемента, поток проверяет сколько времени прошло с момента добавления, если меньше 30 секунд, дальше засыпает на разницу времени, если больше то удаляет элемент и проверяет следующий.

Особенности:
а) придется заниматься синхронизацией, если родительский контейнер не синхронизованный

Примеры писать надеюсь не надо? :)

Comment: Спасибо, направление понял. Но разве при такой реализации, не будет такого, что элементы, которые находятся в контейнере больше 30 секунд не удалятся, пока не добавятся новые? И еще решит ли проблему синхронизации использование списка из библиотеки канкаренси CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Comment: Ты проснешься после первого добавления, поток проверит когда истечет 30 секунд и заснет на нужный интервал, потом проснется когда надо будет удалять, удалит и заснет пока не подойдет время следующего.
Т.е. будить поток при добавлении нужно только в случае, если контейнер был пустой до появления элемента, в противном случае поток сам знает когда ему просыпаться.

Answer (score 0):

Очередь приоритетов по дате и времени, нужно сравнивать текущее время с датой только самого первого элемента в очереди.